# Map of Pre-Hilbert Space is affine if it is an isometry

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, inner-products, alternative-proof

Let $(H, <\cdot ,\cdot>)   $ be a real pre-Hilbert space and let $T: H \to H$ be an isometry so that $||T(x)-T(y)|| = ||x - y||$ for all $x, y \in H$. Prove $T$ is affine.

How do I prove this?

Comment: What is your definition of "affine" here? I haven't seen it used in this context before.

Comment: $T $ is affine if and only if there exists a linear map $L: H \to H $ and $x_0 \in H $ such that $T(x) = Lx + x_0$

Comment: Ah, we aren't assuming that $T$ itself is linear. The question makes sense now:)

Comment: Exaclty, that would be trivial then, but we don't know that  $T(0) = 0$ so $T$  is not necessarily linear.

Comment: You can't prove that $T$ is surjective; that doesn't follow.

Comment: You are right, that should be true if $T(0) = 0$, shouldn't it?

Comment: No, $T(0)$ does not imply it's surjective. Consider the right shift on $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$. That's a non-surjective linear isometry.

Comment: @NateEldredge but we can't prove that $T$ is surejective

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace $T$ by $S(x) = T(x) - T(0)$.  $S$ is an isometry with
 $S(0) = 0$, and  the task is to prove that $S$ is linear.

Now $S$ preserves both distances and norms.  Writing out
$$
||S(a)-S(b)||^2 = d(S(a), S(b))^2 = d(a, b)^2  = ||a-b||^2,
$$
and expanding gives $$\langle S(a), S(b)\rangle  = \langle a, b \rangle.$$
  Using this, compute 
$$
\langle S(a + \lambda b) - S(a) - \lambda S(b), 
 S(a + \lambda b) - S(a) - \lambda S(b)\rangle = 0.
$$
Hence $S(a + \lambda b) - S(a) - \lambda S(b) = 0$, and $S$ is linear.

Addendum:  Maybe the last step is more palatable in the following form:
For all elements $S(z)$ in the range of $S$, one has
$$
\langle S(a + \lambda b) - S(a) - \lambda S(b), S(z) \rangle = 0.
$$
Hence for all $y$ in the linear span of the range (which we have to consider as we don't yet know the range is a linear space), 
$$
\langle S(a + \lambda b) - S(a) - \lambda S(b), y \rangle = 0.
$$
Hence, in particular,
$$
\langle S(a + \lambda b) - S(a) - \lambda S(b), 
 S(a + \lambda b) - S(a) - \lambda S(b)\rangle = 0.
$$

Comment:  Every *complex* inner product spaces is in particular a real inner product space under $(a, b) \mapsto \operatorname{Re}\langle a, b\rangle $, and the real inner product gives, of course, the same norm.  So an isometry is necessarily *real* affine.

Comment: Much cleaner than mine...